# Is there a way to make a voronoi texture smaller and more detailed than its "limit" on a large plane?

Tags: modeling

I tried changing other values but it didn't make the texture "smaller" like it is on the other plane, and I was unable to figure out a way to make a bunch of smaller planes that flowed together.[image]

[image: trying to give it the same texture as the smaller one]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just scaled the large plane up in *Object Mode* than the size of the texture is scaled with the object. To get the texture smaller you have to apply the scale i.e. make it the "natural" size of the object by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Scale*. If you wanted to skip this step, you should have scaled the plane in *Edit Mode* instead of *Object Mode*.

In the example below, the larger plane is scaled 5 times the size of the small plane, so the *Voronoi* texture is 5 times larger as well:

[image: large scale]

After applying the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, the size of the plane is now it's "natural" size which means this is scale X/Y/Z = 1. Notice however that applying the scale does not give the *Displacement* modifier more geometry to work with:

[image: applied scale]

To get the same amount of detail you either have to subdivide the plane further in *Edit Mode* or you could do it procedurally without changing the actual mesh by adding a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and placing it **above** the displacement, so you first have more geometry and then it gets displaced. Set it to *Simple* instead of the default *Catmull-Clark* if you only want a higher resolution without smoothing:

[image: higher subdivision]

I could have set *Levels* even higher to get a more detailed result, but since the original small plane has a low resolution I was fine with levels 2.

Also note that changing and applying scale not only influences the resolution of the displacement, but also the height.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I did not know of this apply scale feature.

Comment: @kepich This is very useful and you should always pay attention to it. Because many issues arise from not applied scales, especially obvious is the three axes are not scaled the same. For example, let's say you have a cube and scale is XYZ = (1, 3, 5). Then you use a _Bevel_ modifier set to a bevel amount of 0.1 m, in this case the visual bevel would result in 0.1 m on X, 0.3 m on Y and 0.5 m on Z. Questions like why edges are not beveled evenly etc. are asked very often on this site.